# What are the relative merits of CSV, JSON and XML for a REST API?

Tags: xml, json, api, rest, csv

We're currently planning a new `API` for an application and debating the various data formats we should use for interchange. There's a fairly intense discussion going on about the relative merits of `CSV`, `JSON` and `XML`.

Basically, the crux of the argument is whether we should support `CSV` at all because of the lack of recursion (***i.e. having a document which has `multiple authors` and `multiple references` would require `multiple API calls` to obtain all the `information`***).

In the experiences you may have had when working with information from `Web APIs` and things we can do to make the lives easier for the developers working with our `API`.

---

**Our decision:**

> We've decided to provide `XML` and `JSON` due to the difficulty in recursion in `CSV` needing multiple calls for a single logical operation. `JSON` doesn't have a parser in `Qt` and `Protocol Buffers` doesn't seem to have a `non-alpha PHP` implementation so they are out for the moment too but will probably be supported eventually.

Comment: The beauty of CSV is in its simplicity.

Comment: CSV is simpler and more efficient for strictly tabular data. Trying to shoehorn something else (as in this case) into CSV is disaster.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CSV is right out.  JSON is a more compact object notation than XML, so if you're looking for high volumes it has the advantage.  XML has wider market penetration (I love that phrase) and is supported by all programming languages and their core frameworks.  JSON is getting there (if not already there).

Personally, I like the brackets.  I would bet more devs are comfortable with working with xml data than with json.

Answer (score 24):

Advantages:

- XML - Lots of libraries, Devs are familiar with it, XSLT, Can be easiily Validated by both client and server (XSD, DTD), Hierarchical Data
- JSON - easily interpreted on client side, compact notation, Hierarchical Data
- CSV - Opens in Excel(?)

Disadvantages:

- XML - Bloated, harder to interpret in JavaScript than JSON
- JSON - If used improperly can pose a security hole (don't use eval), Not all languages have libraries to interpret it.
- CSV - Does not support hierarchical data, you'd be the only one doing it, it's actually much harder than most devs think to parse valid csv files (CSV values can contain new lines as long as they are between quotes, etc).

Given the above, I wouldn't even bother supporting CSV.  The client can generate it from either XML or JSON if it's really needed.

Comment: Unless you have a JSON parser in your language of choice then CSV is far easier to parse than JSON.

Comment: There are JSON parsers available for a very wide range of languages. See the bottom of http://www.json.org/.

Answer (score 3):

XML can be a bit heavyweight at times. JSON is quite nice, though, has good language support, and JSON data can be translated directly to native objects on many playforms.

Answer (score 2):

CSV has so many problems as a complex data model that I wouldn't use it.
XML is very flexible and easy to program with - clients will have no problem coding XML generators and parsers, you can even provide sample parsers using SAX.

Have you checked out Google's network data format? It's called Protocol Buffers. Don't know if it is useful for a REST service however as it skips that whole HTTP layer too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any experience with JSON, CSV works up to a point when your data is very tabular and evenly structured. XML can become unwieldy very quickly, especially if you don't have a tool that creates the bindings to your objects automatically.

I have not tried this either but [Google's Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) look really good, simple format, creates automatic bindings to C++, Java and Python and implements serialisation and deserialisation of the created objects.

Answer (score 1):

Asides from [what Allain Lalonde already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138973/679240), one additional advantage of CSV is that it tends to be more compact than XML or even JSON. So, if your data is *strictly* tabular, with a completely flat hyerarchy, CSV may be a correct choice. Additonal disadvantages of CSV is that it may use different delimiters and decimal separators, depeding on which tool (and even country!) generated it.