# How to create session/cookie on the server with classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm working on a shopping cart and I need to know what is the best/secure way to create session or cookie on the server. By the way I'm using classic asp.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996884/session-in-classic-asp

Comment: look here for tutorial on cookies and sessions http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_cookies.asp http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Comment: @Bernhard, Thanks for mentioning this, but I think in that article nobody talked about security and making it server side....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enable session on your IIS setting(if you are on 2003-2008 servers).
On 2000 server it is enabled by default.

Then use simple variable assign-retrieve techniques.

To assign value use: session("name")= value

To retrieve value: value=session("name")

"name" is your assigned variable for which you want to have value to be preserved for duration of the session.

This way you always have your values secured and available for this specific customer and only for this session.
Any other client will have his own set of values. And basically it is impossible to hack since those value discarded as soon as session ended.

Difference between classic asp session variable and NET session view state is that classic variables not written anywhere on the page and could not be hacked. 
NET on the other hand using session state which is written on each page and potentially can be hacked pretty easily.

Comment: You can do lot of fun staff using session variable but need to keep in mind that if you have high volume of traffic on your site then you will need pretty powerful server with huge memory resources. Since session eat up server memory fast on high traffic sites. Do the math how well you going to utilize traffic vs resources of the server before you decide which way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It was very clear. Just a quick quastion, is there any way you can store session in specific path?