# Json or CSV to web service with large amount of data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, csv

I have a list of objects that I send to web service.
In csv it has **5kb** and in JSon it has **15kb** and this can be larger based on amount of data.
Because this is the first time that I send large amount of data to web service I need advice should I use JSon or CSV to send to ws?
What is the best practice?
I am most worried about performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advantages:**

JSON - easily interpreted on client side, compact notation, Hierarchical Data

CSV - Opens in Excel(?)

**Disadvantages:**

JSON - If used improperly can pose a security hole (don't use eval), Not all languages have libraries to interpret it.

CSV - Does not support hierarchical data, you'd be the only one doing it, it's actually much harder than most devs think to parse valid csv files (CSV values can contain new lines as long as they are between quotes, etc).

For MoreDetail See this link.

[THis is the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138929/what-are-the-merits-of-csv-and-or-json-and-or-xml-and-or-output-in-a-rest-ap)